# How do I make this sphere follow this bezier curve

Tags: cycles-render-engine, path

Please help I cant find how to move the ball along the path! any help would be huge thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a curve and a mesh (sphere)

Go to edit mode and with the start verts selected press shift+s cursor to selected. Press tab to object Mode

Now select the sphere and press shift+S and select selection to cursor

Now select the sphere and curve and press Ctrl+P and select follow path

In the timeline press play the animation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the clamp to constraint.
look at my example gif
[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the "Follow-Path"-Constraint on the Sphere with your curve as the target.

[image: Screenshot]